# How to see Go func len() Implementation in VS Code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

My goal is to see the logic behind func len() in Golang. I use VS Code for IDE.

The problem is when I tried to do `Go to Implementation`, it returns `No implementation found for 'len'`.

What I've did:

1. Install Go extension in VS Code, and install Go binary.
2. I can do `Go to Definition`, the IDE will open `builtin.go`. However, `builtin.go` only contains `func len(v Type) int` without a body.

Comment: `len` is a [built-in 'pseudofunction'](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#len); you won't be able to see its implementation in your IDE.

Comment: To amplify @jub0bs' statement a bit: built-ins are recognized by the compiler and turned into open code (sequences of instructions that are built into the compiler), or calls to secret implementation functions, or whatever is appropriate. For documentation purposes, however, Go includes "fake" or "pretend" source modules that don't actually contain any code, but which some editors, IDEs, and so on will *think* is the function. Those will show you the fake. You're expected to recognize that this *is* a fake and realize that the compiler does something on its own here.

Comment: So, is it possible to see it and if so, how?

Comment: Note that this is no different than certain operators: for instance, `r, ok := <-c` compiles to a function call as well. You can't see the name of this function; it's built in to the compiler. But the channel receive operation here doesn't resemble a function call syntactically, so your editor or IDE doesn't offer you a chance to view the fake function that isn't there.

Comment: You can compile your function to assembly code (or disassemble the compiled code). In most cases, `len` is expanded in line: for instance `len` of a slice that's known to be non-nil is a single instruction. `len` of a slice that might be nil is typically two or three instructions (depending on the CPU).

Comment: Check the go compiler source code and the specific asm libraries for your environment

Comment: @BaytaDarell: that's not always the case: `len` on a *channel* typically turns into a function call.

Comment: Not sure about `r, ok := <-c` or `channel`, I just started learning Go last night. I think I am asking at the wrong time. I will get back here after I finished learning all of Go syntax.

Comment: Well-hearted tip: You are not going to learn _anything_ from looking at the source code of builtin functions and operators if you started to learn the language.